Fit multitype Spatial Point Cox Process
I'm trying to fit Bivariate Cox models for forest species, but it returns an error as shown below, and I don't see another formulation of these models in the Spatstat package.
fit1 <- kppm(Copaif.xylop.ppp~marks, "LGCP")
Error in kppm.ppp(X = Copaif.xylop.ppp, trend = ~marks, data = NULL, clusters = "LGCP") : 
  Sorry, cannot handle marked point patterns

I tried to use the ants dataset for illustration
library(spatstat)
data(ants)
kppm(ants~marks, "LGCP")


The spatstat package does not yet support fitting multitype Cox point process models.

Thank you for your response. Could you please suggest a possible package I could use to fit these models, since the spatstat package is not suitable for this purpose?
